# access an excel file located at /app/webroot/files in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

How do I access an Excel file that is located at /app/webroot/files in a cakephp application inside a controller? I tried this:

```
Router::url('/files/my_excel_file_name.xlsx', true);
```

But that says that the file does not exists

Help please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the [Global Constants](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html)

In this particular case you might want to simple write this

```
WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'yourFile.xlsx';
```

Of course, I am assuming that this path is going to be used by your script (controller) and not within a link (view)